# How do I reorganise a hash similar to a table transpose in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Lets say I have the following hash that represents a multi-dimensional question and answer matrix:

`{'Are you male?' => {'Yes' => {'Do you have children?' => {'No' => '75%', 'Yes' => '25%'}}}}`

How would I programmatically reorganise the hash so that it looks like this:

`{'Do you have children?' => {'No' => {'Are you male?' => {'Yes' => '75%'}}, 'Yes' => {'Are you male?' => {'Yes' => '25%'}}}}`

Comment: Is there any reason you don't create the hash like that?

Comment: Lets say the has represents data loaded in from an excel sheet. You need to be able to access the final values from the row or the column first, so you need to be able to programmatically go from the one or the other and back.

Comment: Your result hash is not well formed ('Are you male?' and 'Yes' are both keys at the same level). Additionally, it's not clear that the transformation you're proposing retains the same information as the original format.

Comment: Data in your desired format is wrong (the 75/25 should be the other way around) (if the original data is to be trusted, of course)

Comment: Edited. To clarify, a 'No' and 'Yes' combination is 75% and a 'Yes' and 'Yes' combination is 25%.

Answer (score 0):

Use the original excel sheet, if possible. If not, I'd do it via intermediate form. Flatten your hash to a CSV file/string:

```
Are you male?, Do you have children?, percentage
Yes, Yes, 25%
Yes, No, 75%
```

From this you can easily reconstruct whatever alternative nesting you need.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Store the questions in combination as a hash key representing (Row)|(Column), and then put the actual options and values in an array. Then switch questions in the hash key and transpose the array. So:

`{'Are you male?|Do you have children?' => [[nil, 'Yes', 'No'],['Yes', '25%', '75%']]}`

becomes:

`{'Do you have children?|Are you male?' => [[nil, "Yes"], ["Yes", "25%"], ["No", "75%"]]}`